# spring boot with spring security: change contextPath

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, contextpath

I have a basic springboot application with spring security added in.
 When I change the application context path by specifying server.context-path (say /xyz) in application.properties, all endpoints except spring security change as expected to /xyz/endpoint1.
Spring security still redirects unauthenticated requests with a 302 to /login.

Is there anyway to force spring security to respect the context path set in spring boot config?

Comment: You should need to do anything to have Spring Security respect the context path. How have you configured the login page?

Comment: I am using the default spring security login page - for now

Comment: My Bad - I was using an incorrect profile - this works fine as expected when I pass it correct program arguments